# Pipeline Task Report Generator fails

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a test coverage report in Azure DevOps pipelines but I get `The report file "path" is invalid. File does not exist.`

Before I run this failing task, I run a task to execute the tests, and I see that task `runTestsWithJacoco`, defined in the build.gradle to create a Jacoco report is `SKIPPED`.

I'm using gradle 7.0.1 and jacoco version 0.8.7.

The gradle buil for project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.jacoco_version = "0.8.7"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacoco_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: PropertiesPlugin

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The gradle.build for app

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = jacoco_version
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

android {
    testOptions {

        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }

        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

task runTestsWithJacoco(
        type: JacocoReport,
        dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest'],
        group: 'Reporting',
        description: 'Running my tests with jacoco'
) {

    def coverageSourceDirs = [
            "src/main/java"
    ]

    def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
            '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*'
    ]

    def javaClasses = fileTree(
            dir: buildDir,
            includes: ['intermediates/javac/debug/classes/**'],
            excludes: fileFilter
    )

    classDirectories.from(files([ javaClasses ]))
    additionalSourceDirs.from(files(coverageSourceDirs))
    sourceDirectories.from(files(coverageSourceDirs))
    executionData.from(fileTree(dir: buildDir, includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
    ]))

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: Gradle@2
  name: run_unit_tests
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: 'app/build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: ':app:runTestsWithJacoco'

- task: reportgenerator@4
  name: generate_report
  inputs:
    reports: 'app/build/reports/jacoco/runTestsWithJacoco/runUnitTestsWithCoverage.xml'
    targetdir: 'coverage'
    sourcedirs: 'service/src/main/java'
    reporttypes: 'Badges;HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura'
```

Why does `reportgenerator@4` fail?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue in `reportgenerator@4` task.

[image]

The root cause of this issue can be that the publishing path you set is invalid.

You can check the build log in Gradle task and check if you can see the following log record:

[image]

To solve this issue, you can try the following sample:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  name: run_unit_tests
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: ':app:runTestsWithJacoco'

- task: reportgenerator@4
  name: generate_report
  inputs:
    reports: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/build/test-results/TEST-*.xml'
    targetdir: 'coverage'
    sourcedirs: 'service/src/main/java'
    reporttypes: 'Badges;HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I tried this but it was failing still. I ended up changing the build agent from ubuntu to macOS and that stopped it from falling. I don't know the reason why it was failing with ubuntu.

Comment: @Liz. Glad to know that this issue can be resolved in MacOS. You can share the method in answer and accept it. This will be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the build agent from Ubuntu to MacOS and that stopped the build from falling. I don't know the reason why it was failing with Ubuntu.